# Optimize Duplicate Detection

Tags: perl, bash, optimization, big-o, code-duplication

## Background

This is an optimization problem. Oracle Forms XML files have elements such as:

```
<Trigger TriggerName="name" TriggerText="SELECT * FROM DUAL" ... />
```

Where the `TriggerText` is arbitrary SQL code. Each SQL statement has been extracted into uniquely named files such as:

```
sql/module=DIAL_ACCESS+trigger=KEY-LISTVAL+filename=d_access.fmb.sql     
sql/module=REP_PAT_SEEN+trigger=KEY-LISTVAL+filename=rep_pat_seen.fmb.sql
```

I wrote a script to generate a list of exact duplicates using a brute force approach.

## Problem

There are 37,497 files to compare against each other; it takes 8 minutes to compare one file against all the others. Logically, if `A = B` and `A = C`, then there is no need to check if `B = C`. So the problem is: how do you eliminate the redundant comparisons?

The script will complete in approximately 208 days.

## Script Source Code

The comparison script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Loading directory ...

for i in $(find sql/ -type f -name \*.sql); do
        echo Comparing $i ...

        for j in $(find sql/ -type f -name \*.sql); do
                if [ "$i" = "$j" ]; then
                        continue;
                fi

                # Case insensitive compare, ignore spaces
                diff -IEbwBaq $i $j > /dev/null

                # 0 = no difference (i.e., duplicate code)
                if [ $? = 0 ]; then
                        echo $i :: $j >> clones.txt
                fi
        done
done
```

## Question

How would you optimize the script so that checking for cloned code is a few orders of magnitude faster?

### Idea #1

Remove the matching files into another directory so that they don't need to be examined twice.

## System Constraints

Using a quad-core CPU with an SSD; trying to avoid using cloud services if possible. The system is a Windows-based machine with Cygwin installed -- algorithms or solutions in other languages are welcome.

Thank you!

Comment: Two initial questions: 1) Will the data in "duplicate" files always be in the same order, or can lines be out-of-order? I assume the former since you're using `diff`; 2) To be considered a duplicate, can we assume it *has* to be case sensitive? I assume insensitive since you specifically use `diff` with a case-insensitive compare - but a better method exists if it's case-sensitive.

Comment: 1) The files should be returned in the same order; this could be forced using a sort command or an argument to `find`. 2) The case needs to match insensitively; files differing only by white space and blank lines must be considered duplicate code.

Comment: If you want performance, bash script isn't a good idea.

Comment: Bash isn't the problem, Dani (although I agree a C-based solution would execute faster, but even if it only took 30 seconds [instead of 8 minutes] to compare all 37,000 files, that's still 12 days). The algorithm is `O(n^2)` in any language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution, and sputnick's solution, both take O(n^2) time.  This can be done in O(nlog n) time by sorting the files and using a list merge.  It can be sped up further by comparing MD5 (or any other cryptographically-strong hash function) of the files, instead of the files themselves.

Assuming you're in the `sql` directory:

```
md5sum * | sort > ../md5sums
perl -lane 'print if $F[0] eq $lastMd5; $last = $_; $lastMd5 = $F[0]' < ../md5sums
```

Using the above code will report only exact byte-for-byte duplicates.  If you want to consider two non-identical files to be equivalent for the purposes of this comparison (e.g. if you don't care about case), first create a canonicalised copy of each file (e.g. by converting every character to lower case with `tr A-Z a-z < infile > outfile`).

Comment: Case and white space must be ignored. Good idea about the hash; I was also thinking about simply moving the matching files to another directory.

Comment: Whitespace can be deleted with `tr -d ' \r\n\t'`.

Comment: Thank you! I squeezed it with `tr -s`.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to hash each file, like SHA-1, and then use a set. I'm not sure bash can do this, but python can. Although if you want best performance C++ is the way to go.

Answer (score -1):

To optimize comparison of your files :

```
#!/bin/bash

for i; do
    for j; do
        [[ "$i" != "$j" ]] &&
            if diff -IEbwBaq "$i" "$j" > /dev/null; then
                echo "$i & $j are the same"
            else
                echo "$i & $j are different"
            fi
    done
done
```

**USAGE**

```
./script /dir/*
```

Comment: `cmp` doesn't provide a case-insensitive, or whitespace-ignoring, comparison.